# Stop guest VM powering off when switching machines?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, kvm-switch

I have two machines, both windows. I'm using VM Workstation 11 in one.

If I have the VM running on one machine, and I switch to the other one for ~5 minutes, it appears as though the VM powers off.

How do I stop this from happening, as it closes my work when it does so?

I've googled but I found nothing on SO, or the VM websites, but it's possible I've missed something.

Comment: The machine is only being suspended.  It would happen regardless. Just disable it from being [suspended](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2056501)

Comment: @Ramhound which machine is being suspended? The VM is definitely powered off. The link you provided is for VM Fusion 3-7 and Workstation 8-9 by the looks of it. But I'll have a look.

Comment: I used Workstation extensively and I know exactly what your talking about.  Your virtual machines are being suspended if its after 5 minutes because of inactivity not because your switching to another running virtual machine.

Comment: @Ramhound [this](http://superuser.com/a/893459/113848) doesn't seem to have worked. If I leave it long enough it does shut down. I can tell as when I power it back up (unlike when suspended) none of my programs are still running. Any advice/thoughts?

Comment: @Ramhound I figured out what it is. <kbd>ctrl+alt+del</kbd> sets a timer in the Linux gues VM that will eventually switch off the machine. It also (normally) locks the Windows machine too fast to notice.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions, as linked by [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/questions/893440/stop-guest-vm-powering-off-when-switching-machines?noredirect=1#comment1195391_893440), are from [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2056501):

1. Shutdown the virtual machine.
2. [Locate the virtual machine folder.](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1003880)

   1. Select the virtual machine from the VMware application window
   2. Click VM > Settings.
   3. Click Options.
   4. Click Advanced.
   5. Under File locations you will see Configuration and Log. You can find the files in those directories.
3. [Open the .vmx file for editing in a text editor.](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=2057902)
4. Add this line to the .vmx file:
   `suspend.disabled = "TRUE"`
5. Save and close the .vmx file.
6. Restart the virtual machine.